# Hiding an element completly that has had some overflow hidden

Tags: css, overflow, hidden, element

Basically I have a parent div with height and width and overflow:hidden and then within that some more divs with it.
We are dealing with fluid content and some of the divs go over the corners so get hidden.
But one is half and half.
Is there a way to make that completely hidden?

CSS would be best.

Comment: Can you post a SS or some code please?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can know if a child from an `overflow:hidden` parent is in the hidden or visible section without using Javascript (I might be wrong here).

What I suggest is that you set all the child divs to a fixed dimension `d` and set the parent div to a multiple of `d` so every child is either completely visible of not.

This solution won't work if you fill your divs with different-length content

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your post, you have a wrapping div that has overflow:hidden and you want to make any child element hidden unless it can be completely displayed within the wrapping div.

There may be a better way to do it, but I would use a CSS media query. If you're unsure of how they work this is a good place to start: 
http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Using this method, you could determine how many blocks of each type should be displayed on any given set of resolutions. I'd be interested in seeing how it goes, or if you end up using a different approach. Best of luck!

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but only supported in firefox and opera IE is a no go. Thanks though for the post it's probably as close an answer as there is going to be!

Comment: Yeah, the problem child of the internet...I think that article brings up a solution to this. If I remember correctly, you go about setting up your layouts normally then to make it work for IE you add a pretty simple bit of javascript to do the logic around screen size and which stylesheet to load (for IE).