# How to hide child element entirely if it is cut off by it's parent's overflow:hidden property?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` element with child nodes.  This `div` is set up to hide any overflow.  However, I've noticed that if a child element overflows this parent `div` then it is cut off.  What I would prefer would be for this specific child element to be hidden completely if it overflows its parent.

Here's some example HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
        #tags {
            width: 120px;
            overflow:hidden;
            white-space:nowrap;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tags">
            <span class="tag"><a href="#tag1">tag 1</a></span>
            <span class="tag"><a href="#tag2">tag 2</a></span>
            <span class="tag"><a href="#tag3">tag 3</a></span>
            <span class="tag"><a href="#tag4">tag 4</a></span>
            <span class="tag"><a href="#tag5">tag 5</a></span>
            <span class="tag"><a href="#tag6">tag 6</a></span>
            <span class="tag"><a href="#tag7">tag 7</a></span>
            <span class="tag"><a href="#tag8">tag 8</a></span>
            <span class="tag"><a href="#tag9">tag 9</a></span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Rendering this code in a browser shows the first three tags, but the fourth is cut in half.  How can I structure my CSS so that this fourth item would be hidden completely instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hiding an element completly that has had some overflow hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005402/hiding-an-element-completly-that-has-had-some-overflow-hidden)

Comment: That's not possible with CSS alone. The best you could do is force a height on the containing div and get rid of white-space:nowrap. Then the extra items will wrap onto the next line but they will not be seen because of the overflow:hidden.

Comment: @skyline3000 Actually, your comment is exactly the answer I was looking for.  Care to submit it as an actual answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force a height on the containing `div` and remove `white-space:nowrap`. The extra items will wrap onto the next line but they will not be seen because of the `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: Gaaaa leeee this is genius! Just so this comment is somewhat useful. If the parent is a flexbox. `white-space:nowrap` would turn into `flex-wrap: wrap`